# Can't convert a byte string back to a string

Tags: python, string, encryption, utf-8, rsa

I'm working on a project that allows people to exchange encrypted messages.

I believe the problem is to do with when i transmit the encrypted message. I pass a string (the message) to this function

```
    def sendInfo(host, port, sendObject):

        socit = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print("#Connecting")
        socit.connect((host, port))
        print("#Sending")
        #sendObject = unicode(sendObject, 'utf-8')
        #bites = str.encode(sendObject)

        bites = bytes(sendObject)
        print str(bites)
        #bites = pickle.dumps(sendObject)
        socit.send(bites)

        socit.close()

        print("Sent successfully")
```

An example of the transmitted message I get out is:

```
"'\x02\xc6\x07\xa5\xb1\xc4t\xd4\x8e\xf1e\xc3r\x17\xc6T\xec\x9bm\xbe\xf8\xb4J3\x9d\xeej\xf2N\xec\x8a\xc1\xbf\xdc\xe8\x8f\xc3\x1d\n\xea\x9b\x02\x99i\\o\xb3\xed\x7f-\x0b4]f}\x8f\x1e\xdcJ\xefo\xabR\x1a\x14N/O"\xa5\xa8X\xa5\xd9\xf2\xfb\xab7\xf7\xd67\xd4Y\xa1\x85\x9a\xfc\xfe\x8d\x03\',\x89k|NY"\xbc\x7f\xe0\x0b\xc56\xd6G\xc3Y\xac\x98\x88\x1fn\x8bz\xcaMi\xfd\xe4Lj\xa3\xbc'"
```

Which I then convert into this which I hope is acceptable utf-8:

```
"(x02\xc6\x07\xa5\xb1\xc4t\xd4\x8e\xf1e\xc3r\x17\xc6T\xec\x9bm\xbe\xf8\xb4J3\x9d\xeej\xf2N\xec\x8a\xc1\xbf\xdc\xe8\x8f\xc3\x1d\n\xea\x9b\x02\x99i\\o\xb3\xed\x7f-\x0b4]f}\x8f\x1e\xdcJ\xefo\xabR\x1a\x14N/O"\xa5\xa8X\xa5\xd9\xf2\xfb\xab7\xf7\xd67\xd4Y\xa1\x85\x9a\xfc\xfe\x8d\x03\',\x89k|NY"\xbc\x7f\xe0\x0b\xc56\xd6G\xc3Y\xac\x98\x88\x1fn\x8bz\xcaMi\xfd\xe4Lj\xa3\xbc"
```

The code I used to decrypt is based on the pyrsa library (http://stuvel.eu/rsa):

```
def decrypt(message, privKey):
    return rsa.decrypt(message, privacy)
```

The error I get out is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Andrew/Shatter/ShatterListen.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Andrew/Shatter/ShatterListen.py", line 127, in main
    ciphertext = ShatterRSA.decrypt(ciphertext, listenerKey[1])
  File "/Users/Andrew/Shatter/ShatterRSA.py", line 85, in decrypt
    return rsa.decrypt(message, privKey)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py", line 232, in decrypt
    raise DecryptionError('Decryption failed')
DecryptionError: Decryption failed
```

If anyone could shed some light on the situation and make some suggestions on what could be the issue. I'm 90% sure that the transmitted string isn't being decoded correctly and that's where the error is coming from, but I have no idea what I can try. If you want anymore code or information I'm happy to provide it.

EDIT:

Here is some code showing the encryption process in a single module, not being transmitted:

```
key = create_key(1024)
ciphertext = encrypt('Hey there!', key[0])
print ciphertext
print decrypt(ciphertext, key[1])
```

The output of which is:

```
>>> 

Hey there!
>>>
```

Comment: First, in Python 2.x, `str` and `bytes` are the same type, so converting back and forth between the two isn't doing you any good.

Comment: Meanwhile, it looks like you're trying to send the string representation of the string representation of some binary data. Why? And, if that's what you have, it's guaranteed to be ASCII, so why are you worrying about encoding and decoding as UTF-8?

Comment: Anyway, your problem is most likely caused by the fact that you're got the string representation of the string representation of the binary ciphertext, rather than the binary ciphertext, and of course you can't decrypt that.

Comment: One list thing: How exactly are you converting a string representation of a string representation of binary data into a string representation of binary data with the first `\` replaced by a `(`? (And, for that matter, why?)

Comment: I think since it's a byte string and they're the same - I'm just using string operations. I saw some similar errors whilst researching the problem and saw other utf-8 encodings that were in the format "(xxx\xxx\xxx..."

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What is the first sentence an answer to? Also, `(`, `\`, `x`, and digits are all exactly the same characters in UTF-8 that they are in ASCII, so I can't see anything relevant to UTF-8 here. More importantly, I don't get what you're trying to UTF-8-encode, or why, or how encodings even enter into anything you're doing here.

Comment: Honestly, I reached a stage where I was grasping at straws and put in a lot of code I didn't understand too well. My understanding was that I had a string, which was translated into bytes (i.e. serialised) and sent to the receiver. Then it was re-translated to a string, but it seems to receive a string of the serialisation.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "translated into bytes". Again, a Python 2.x string just _is_ bytes. They may be bytes that represent a Unicode string encoded with UTF-8 or Latin-1 or something else, or they may be binary ciphertext or a JPEG image or anything else.

Comment: And if you're doing anything to translate anything, you haven't shown it to us in your code. The only thing you do is call `bytes` on the string, which makes an identical copy of the exact same string, and then call `str` on that, which makes another identical copy.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what kind of conversion code you _could_ be using that changed `\x02` (and I still don't know whether that's four characters with a literal backslash, x, etc., or one character, control-B) into `(x02`, or why anyone would write such code, but I do know that nobody will be able to debug that code without being able to see it.

Comment: I've been trying these to try and serialise the string: `str.encode(sendObject)`, `bytes(sendObject)`, `pickle.dumps(sendObject)` and when I capture that in the receiving terminal i get the output listed above. As far as I'm aware, that's all the translation code.

Comment: OK, first, there's no reason to call `str.encode(s)` when you can just call `s.encode()`. More importantly, calling `encode` without a codec just uses `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is almost never what you want. Please read [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), throw away all the random code, and explain your _real_ problem, not the problem you created while trying to haphazardly solve it.

Comment: More specifically, if you just want to transmit the encrypted bytes that come out of `rsa.encrypt` over a socket to be decrypted, the way to encode that is to do absolutely nothing. To send bytes over a binary socket, you don't need any encoding. Just `sock.sendall` the `str` as-is. If that isn't working, go back to that code, show us where it's failing, and we can show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The byte-string `"(x02\xc6\x07\xa5\xb1\xc4t ..."` is not a valid UTF-8 stream.  After `\xc6`, which starts with bits `110`, the next byte must begin with bits `10` which `\x07` does not.  A good summary of how the encoding works can be found in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

You said you 'converted' the received ciphertext into this string; I assume this was through an RSA decrypt step?  If so, then there are a few things to check:

- you are using the wrong encrypt or decrypt key (same key for both operations, etc)
- the data was otherwise not correctly encrypted
- something is distorting the data between the encrypt and decrypt steps (one possibility would be a packetization scheme that is not the same between sender and receiver)

Comment: Also, you didn't ask, but I hope you're not planning on doing anything "real" with this.  Getting this stuff right takes a long time and a lot of trial by fire.  Use hardened crypto code that has already been battle tested for production applications.

Comment: A run of binary ciphertext is incredibly unlikely to be a valid UTF-8 stream. But I don't think that's his actual problem. He's not even doing any UTF-8 decoding in his code; he's passing these bytes (or, possibly, that's an actual string, with backslashes and x's? I'm still not sure…) to the decrypt function as-is and they're not decrypting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I referred to 'converting' the string, I meant in terms of serialisation of the output for transmission - after encrypting it. The string I posted was before a decryption step. I realise the encryption isn't suitable for a genuine project, this is more of a proof of concept app than one that I expect to be genuinely secure.